# Following instagram standards when processing an image using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, instagram, carrierwave, minimagick

I am currently building a a Rails API backend where users can upload images. I want to process those images following Instagram standards as explained here https://help.instagram.com/1631821640426723. I am currently using carrierwave with Minimagick with Rails 5 in API mode. I've read the documentation of the carrierwave gem but image processing is a bit alien to me. I apreciate the help!